# How does an Eclipse 4 application launch another in a new workbench?

Tags: eclipse, e4

I cannot work out how one pure Eclipse 4 application can launch another pure Eclipse 4 application in a new Workbench. Eclipse itself seems to do this with the Eclipse Marketplace but I don't know how it does this and I don't know if it uses pure E4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal Eclipse launch code is not part of the pure e4 core of Eclipse so you can't use that.

Which means you would have to use the normal Java APIs for running another program such as `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

The normal Eclipse launch code is essentially just an elaborate wrapper around the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` call.

Comment: Thanks Greg, for the very prompt and accurate answer as usual! Sorry for the delay in acknowledging - got diverted.